# How can I restore a ZKDB.db (ZKTeco UA860/ID) file?

Tags: linux

I accidently deleted the database file from ZKTeco UA860/ID Device (`/mnt/mtdblock/data/ZKDB.db`)

How can I restore it?

Comment: Well, given this would seem to be a company device, the company should then  restore it from backups.

Comment: unfortunately, There's nothing in there website

Comment: No, YOUR backups.

Comment: I don't have one

Comment: Well, given that the file is organic & contains local data about  local users, there is nothing we can do. You have to start over. Next time, start taking backups of all data.

Comment: I Just need empty database file
I have all the user data but the device main menu can't be opend when ZKDB.db file is empty without any table
If you have this device telnet to it with root:solokey then copy the /mnt/mtdblock/data/ZKDB.db file to USB flash mem
cp /mnt/mtdblock/data/ZKDB.db /mnt/usbdisk/

Comment: @Aliali - Providing an empty database won’t help you.

Comment: check this script https://github.com/htlcnn/scripts/blob/master/zkdevice.py it may give you clues on the format to recreate the tables

Answer (score 1):

I took a backup for another ZKTeco model and extract the `ZKDB.db` file then move it to my device, Now it's works fine.